# The constraint_orientation setting does not work in script

Tags: python

The function I wrote below:

```
def dc(period,mvtype,axis,mval,boolx,booly,boolz):

    v3d = [x for x in bpy.context.screen.areas if x.type == 'VIEW_3D']
    v3d[0].spaces[0].transform_orientation = 'axes-'+ bpy.context.active_object.name  
    ob = bpy.context.active_object

    mtx = bpy.context.scene.objects['axes-'+bpy.context.active_object.name].matrix_world
    if axis == 'x':
        vec = mathutils.Vector((mtx[0][0], mtx[1][0], mtx[2][0]))
    elif axis == 'y':
        vec = mathutils.Vector((mtx[0][1], mtx[1][1], mtx[2][1]))
    elif axis == 'z':
        vec = mathutils.Vector((mtx[0][2], mtx[1][2], mtx[2][2]))
    else:
         return

    inv = ob.matrix_world.copy()
    inv.invert()
    # align to custom axis
    mv = vec * inv * mval
    ob.select=True

    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=mv,constraint_axis=(boolx, booly, boolz),constraint_orientation='axes-1')

    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    ob.select=True
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob
    return

# call the function by
dc(0,8,'y',1,  False, True, False)
```

But in the info panel:
`bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(XXXXX, XXXXX, 0), constraint_axis=(False, True, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)`

The constraint_orientation is "global" rather than "axes-1" as i set.
Any reason of that ?